# How to output to a file the number of logins and number of users to particular page on a website in my selenium script c# visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, sql, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, azure-cosmosdb

I am an automated tester using selenium c# in Visual Studio 2017.  I would like to know how I can get the number of users who logged in and choose a particular page from pressing an icon (maybe write these to a file).  The database we are using in cosmosdb and sql.  Can this be done in my automated scripts?

Comment: I'm a bit confused- are you trying to get the stats from your tests or are you trying to include stats from users in the production application?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I guess its stats from users which in turn would mean the server is being used, does that make sense?...and yes in the production application

Comment: So just making sure I understand the end goal- are you just looking to get a readout of user statistics or are you looking to incorporate them into your tests somehow? Assuming the metrics are being stored and you have access to them, you should be able to do either scenario. It's likely going to be independent of Selenium itself, but if I can understand what your end goal is I should be able to help.

Comment: This is nothing related to selenium. You may need a website stats for the user interaction or operation that are being performed on your website. You can use some analytics tools like google analytics which will provide not only this stats, but many other.